# Allowing only certain packets based on payload with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I would like to create a rule to allow only packets with this payload (marked on the image). Could someone help me create the iptables rule using u32 module?
Here is the link:

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
iptables -m u32 --u32 "N&0xffffff=0x95ca57b7"
```

Where **N** is first byte offset - 3.

In the picture above, the first selected byte has offset 31 (starting from 1), Thus N = 28 (31-3), The filter then looks like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m u32 --u32 "28&0xffffff=0x95ca57b7" -j ACCEPT
```